# Extend TikZ/pgfplots axis arrows without grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I extend axis arrows outside of the grid without also extending the grid?

This is the closest I can get:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line  = center,
    axis y line  = center,
    xlabel       = {$\mathrm{V}$},
    ylabel       = {$\mathrm{I}$},
    xlabel style = {anchor = west},
    ylabel style = {above left},
    xmin         = -5,
    xmax         = 6,
    ymin         = -5,
    ymax         = 6,
    xtick        = {-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick        = {-5,-4,...,5},
    grid         = both,
    grid style   = {dashed, gray},
    legend pos   = outer north east
  ]
    \addplot [domain=-5:5,samples=2,mark=*,red] {x/1.667};
    \addplot [domain=-5:5,samples=2,mark=*,blue] {0};
    \legend{
      $R=\SI{1.667}{\ohm}$,
      {open circuit}
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As you can see, the grid also enlarges by `10pt`. How can I make the grid stop at x=5 and y=5?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please externd your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

One way how you can achieve desired diagram layout is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines  = middle,
axis line style = {shorten > =-5mm},
    xlabel       = {$V$},
    ylabel       = {$I$},
    xlabel style = {xshift=5mm, right},
    ylabel style = {yshift=5mm,  left},
%
    xmin         = -5,  xmax         = 5,
    ymin         = -5,  ymax         = 5,
    xtick        = {-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick        = {-5,-4,...,5},
    grid         = both,
    grid style   = {dashed, gray},
    legend pos   = outer north east,
    domain=-5:5,
            ]
    \addplot +[samples=2] {x/1.667};
    \addplot +[samples=2] {0};
    \legend{
      $R=\SI{1.667}{\ohm}$,
      {open circuit}
    }
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I believe this is the way to do it - I do not see it as a dirty trick at all. A dirty trick would draw on top of the existing line or adjunct which could create viewer artefacts.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, you are right.  I will correct this sentence.